# How to read data from a POSTGRESQL database using DAS?

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server

We are working on the ETL. How to read data from the **POSTGRESQL** data base using streams in **DATA ANALYTICS SERVER** and manipulate some operations using the streams and insert the manipulated data into another **POSTGRESQL** data base on a scheduled time. Please share the procedures to follow.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "PL/SQL database". Do you mean you want to connect to an Oracle database?

Comment: I want to connect POSTGRESQL

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you don't need to publish data from your PostgreSQL server. Using WSO2 Data Analytics Server (DAS) you can pull data from your database and do the analysis. Finally, you can push results back to the PostgreSQL server. In DAS, we have a special connector called "CarbonJDBC" and using that connector you can easily do this.

The current version of the "CarbonJDBC" connector supports following database management systems.

1. MySQL
2. H2
3. MS SQL
4. DB2
5. PostgreSQL
6. Oracle

You can use following query to pull data from your PostgreSQL database and populate a spark table.  Once spark table is populated with data, you can start you data analysis tasks.

```
create temporary table <temp_table> using CarbonJDBC options (dataSource "<datasource name>", tableName "<table name>");  
select * from <temp_table>;
insert into / overwrite table <temp_table> <some select statement>;
```

For more information regarding "CarbonJDBC" connector please refer following blog post [1].

[1]. https://pythagoreanscript.wordpress.com/2015/08/11/using-the-carbon-spark-jdbc-connector-for-wso2-das-part-1/